# runing diffrent programs in multiocore architecture in gem5

Tags: multicore, gem5

I'm very new in gem5. 
I want to run  3 simple programs ,those are difference from the other;
in multi core Architecture;like a system with 3 ARM core.
I set number of cpu=2
and separate 2 programs by using ";" :test1;test2
I try this code for 2 ARM core

```
./build/ARM/gem5.opt --stats="/home/me/me_Test/me_stat.txt" 
./configs/example/se.py --cpu-type=arm_detailed --num-cpu=**2** --caches --l2cache\-c/home /me/eslam_Test/test1/bin/ARM/test1**;**    /home/me/me_Test/me/bin/ARM/test2
```

but I saw this error :

```
bash: /home/me/me_Test/test2/bin/ARM/test2: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

how can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the binary files test1 and test2 might have been built on your system which might be of different architecture. Use a cross compiler to build a binary to run on ARM .